# PHP class inherit variables in included file

Tags: php, class, file, include, extends

I have like:

```
class Class2 extends Class1 {
.....
 function __construct() {
 parent::__construct();
   $var_in_included_file;
}   
}

class Class1 {
function __construct() {
 include_once('my_file.php')
}
.....
}
```

my_file.php:

```
$var_in_included_file=10;
```

The problem is that I cannot receive value of $var_in_included_file. Is there a way to receive this value without add many codice like:

```
$this->var=$var_in_included_file ....?
```

Because I have many thousands of variables.
Thanks.
More abstract the problem is:
in some file I received (from $_POST) near 500 variable.
These variables have be elaborated in complicated way. For simplify this elaborating I need create tree of class inheritans - but in this case these variables will not seen in child classes without assigning them to class variables - but this produses enormous volume of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in [`include()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) and [variable scopes](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php), when you include a file in your `__construct()` method, the scope of the variables in the file you're including is limited to the `__construct()` method, not the class.

Your options would be to either change the content of the included file to include a `$this->` in front of the variable name (i.e. `$this->var_in_included_file = 10;`) or add a `$this->var_in_included_file = $var_in_included_file;` in your `__construct()` method.

Answer (score 2):

In class one, assign your variables to class variables:

```
class Class1{
   private $someVariable;

 public function __construct(){
    include_once 'my_file.php';
     // variable declared in my_file.php        
    $this->someVariable = $someVariable;        
    }       

}
```

Now that variable is accessible in child class, through `$this->someVariable`.

Happy coding, good-luck

Answer (score 0):

```
Class1 {

include_once('my_file.php')
.....
}
```

Is not possible

Comment: also missing the `class` keyword?

Comment: it is for simplisity, clear that it is in function __construct() { }

Comment: This is not code for syntax checking - this is the sense of problem - is there way to receive access to many variables that hidden inside of parent class.

Comment: So the answer is - no, the only way is `$this->varName`